# C# Mail Function not connecting to remote server

Tags: c#, email

I am developing a program which needs to have the capability to send emails.  I've got a simple mail function setup however I have never really delved into the mail side of things and am not sure if I'm using the correct settings.

I am sure I am doing something wrong with the SMTP, I have set the MailMessage host as the outgoing mail server that I use for emailing from outlook (the email accounts are hosted on shared virtual hosting so I use their supplied hostname in the function) alongside the login credentials I would normally use.  When I try to send a test email it throws an unable to connect to remote server exception.  I have WAMPSERVER setup on the computer I am trying to run this from, I know it has some kind of SMTP capability?  Should I be using this or is there no reason I can't use shared virtual hosting SMTP as the host?  Please refer to code below-

```
public void EmailTracking()
    {

        string to = "johnsmith@xxxxxxxxxxxxx.com.au";
        string body = "this is some text for body";
        string subject = "subject line";
        string fromAddress = "kelvie@xxxxxxxxxx.com.au";
        string fromDisplay = "Kelvie";
        string credentialUser = "removed";
        string credentialPassword = "removed";
        string host = "removed";

        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        mail.Body = body;
        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
        mail.To.Add(new MailAddress(to));
        mail.From = new MailAddress(fromAddress, fromDisplay, Encoding.UTF8);
        mail.Subject = subject;
        mail.SubjectEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        mail.Priority = MailPriority.Normal;

        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
        smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(credentialUser, credentialPassword);
        smtp.Host = host;
        smtp.Send(mail);  //fails here with unable to connect to remote server
    }
```

Comment: Have you checked to see if everything is working via telnet?  See: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa995718(v=exchg.65).aspx (or simply search for "Test SMTP Telnet").  Could be the auth required is different (before sent, etc.)

Comment: First of all you should configure a mail client (for eaxmple Outlook) on the same machine as your program and make it work against this very SMTP server. **After** this works, you may try your own program with exactly the same SMTP settings.

Comment: Also: In your code I miss: Port, SSL (yes/no)

Comment: It can also be that you are going through the proxy and require to bypass it...